# Is it ever safe to call a virtual method from a constructor?

Tags: c++, constructor, virtual-functions

I am aware that it is unsafe to call a virtual method from within the constructor of the class in which the method is declared virtual (or pure virtual).

However, I am wondering if the following is safe:

```
class Base
{
public:
    void helper()
    {
        this->foo();
    }

protected:
     virtual void foo() = 0;
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    Derived()
    {
        this->helper();
    }

protected:
    void foo() override
    {
        //...
    }
};
```

Yes, the virtual method `foo()` is called from within a constructor, but it is called from within the constructor for the class which implements `foo()`.

Here is a working example: https://godbolt.org/z/nz4YsbqYT

But, is this well-defined by the standard for all compilers?

Comment: It's always safe to call virtual methods in constructors and destructors. The only problem is, it will call the implementation from this class only (since any derived classes do not exist at the point when constructor/destructor is called). In other terms, the function is not `virtual` at all within constructor/destructor.

Comment: The problem would occur if you called `foo` during the construction of `Base`.

Comment: To add to @molbdnilo's comment: it would also occur if `foo` was not implemented in `Derived`, but only in another class inheriting `Derived`.

Comment: This is exactly as well defined and safe as calling `foo()` directly from the same constructor.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [calling a protected virtual method in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9944923/calling-a-protected-virtual-method-in-c)

Comment: This should help understanding that calling virtual member function from a constructor is a spacial case: https://godbolt.org/z/M9zxo9PGd https://godbolt.org/z/bsdqTncn5 Since you are do not call `foo` from `Base::Base` you are fine.

Comment: @Atmo I guess I should have worded my question differently.  In essence yes, that does answer my question.  But what I am really asking is for the behavior of, once the class containing the implementation HAS been constructed (i.e., not in the abstract Base's constructor), what is the behavior.

Comment: Re: "... class in which the method is declared virtual (or pure virtual)" -- there's a big difference. Plain old virtual is always okay; it calls the function for the type whose constructor is currently running. Pure virtual is okay, too, if the pure virtual function has a definition. Pure virtual means that a derived class must override the function, and that it doesn't have to have a definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am wondering if the following is safe:

Yes, in the example you've given, it is.

> ... is this well-defined for all compilers by the standard?

Yes. `*this` is a `Derived` in the constructor of `Derived`, so `Derived::foo` will be called from `helper`.

Safe? Well... If you expect everyone to know how it works, it is. Someone may however do:

```cpp
class EvenMoreDerived : public Derived {
protected:
    void foo() override {
        std::cout << "not called\n";
    }
};
```

... and, without other additions, expect this version of `foo` to be called when instantiating an `EvenMoreDerived`. That will of course not happen since the call to `helper` is done in the `Derived` constructor, so it'll still be `Derived::foo` that's being called, not `EvenMoreDerived::foo`.

One possible way to avoid mistakes like that if you want to call `virtual` methods in the constructor is to make the class `final`:

```
class Derived final : public Base { // the above mistake will not be so easy to make
};
```

... or make `foo` `final`:

```cpp
class Derived : public Base {
protected:
    void foo() override final {
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

This is all very well-defined. The "problem" is simply that the `this` pointer in the `Base` constructor points to a `Base` object, as the `Derived` part has not been constructed yet. That's why you can't call `Derived::foo()` from the `Base` constructor; there's no `Derived` object to call it on. No special rule, it's just the regular C++ rule that you can't call methods of an object that you haven't yet created (or which you already destroyed, in the case of destructors).

All compilers agree on this; it's not that complex a rule. It's also pretty consistent. The `Base` constructor could throw before the `Derived` constructor can even run, so you can't even say for sure that there will be a `Derived` object eventually. A required resource might be lacking.

But in your case, there's not even such a problem. You're calling `Derived::foo` from the `Derived` constructor, and that's perfectly OK. All base classes and members of `Derived` exist and are initialized at that point.